# Show ISO date values in string form

Tags: django, django-views

So I was trying to get what months that an insurer filed a claim. However, the values were in ISO Form. I was trying to show it in string form. Instead of showing 2021-01-01, show January; 2021-01-02, show February

Here's the sample get data
[Data in image form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dy7mM.png)

```
{
"Month": [
    "2021-04-01T00:00:00+08:00",
    "2021-02-01T00:00:00+08:00",
    "2021-03-01T00:00:00+08:00"
],
"Claim(s)": {
    "": 18,
    "Bank Transfer": 5,
    "CAR": 1,
    "home": 5,
    "Credit": 7,
    "Energy": 1,
    "health": 38,
    "\"health\"": 5
}
```

}

I'd like to change the ISO date form into string form instead.

Here is my code in Views

```
class GetClaimsCompare_year(APIView):
def get_claim_count(self, claims_data, claim_type):
    claims_count = claims_data.filter(claim_type = claim_type).count()
    return claims_count

def get_claims_type(self, claim_per_month):
    return claim_per_month.claim_type

def get(self, request):
    today = datetime.now()
    claims_data = Claims.objects.filter(modified_at__year =today.year)

    claim_per_month = claims_data.annotate(month = TruncMonth('modified_at')).values('month').annotate(claim_type=Count('id'))

    labels = []

    claims_type = list(set(map(self.get_claims_type, claims_data)))

    final = {}

    for claims in claim_per_month:
        labels.append(claims['month'])
        for claim_type in claims_type:
            final[claim_type] = self.get_claim_count(claims_data, claim_type)

    context = {
        'Month':labels,
        'Claim(s)':final
    }
    return Response(context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple call [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) on the datetime that you get

```
...
for claims in claim_per_month:
    month_label = claims['month'].strftime('%B')
    labels.append(month_label)
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! helped my a lot especially I'm not familiar on using the strftime